# Where is the Bathymetry toolbox in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, bathymetry

I can't find the Bathymetry toolbox on my ArcMap 10.4. I went to the customize toolbar but there is no sign of it. I searched in but nothing shows up.

Answer (score 2):

[ArcGIS for Maritime](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/maritime-bathymetry/what-is-arcgis-for-maritime-bathymetry.htm) is an extension not a toolbar.  You will need to go to Customize>Extensions and enable it there.

Comment: There is not such extension in Customize>Extensions.

Comment: What version of ArcMap are you using?  It requires a standard license.

Comment: ArcGIS 10.4 Advanced type

Comment: Sorry to ask this but, have you installed and authorized the extension?

Comment: It is the university license which is provided to students by the University. So, I assume that it is authorized.

Comment: Open ArcGIS Administrator (start menu) and go to Desktop>Availability.  That will show you the extensions that you have licensed.

Comment: It shows available in the ArcGIS Administrator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53828/discussion-between-stephen-ruhl-and-farshad).

Comment: Just to finish this. An authorized extension will show up in the Administrator even if the extension has not been installed.